# How to add html tags to vector in R keeping capital letters?

Tags: r

### My task

I need to add HTML tags to specific words (each occasion) in a string in R in a such way that capital letters remain capital.

### My attempts

The first approach identifies all words but as replacement includes lower case letter in the resulting string all letter are also lower cese:

```
x = "Some random text with some, issues"
gsub(pattern = "some", replacement = "<>some<>", x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

```
[1] "<>some<> random text with <>some<>, issues"
```

Somewhere I found an alternative approach using function which preserves capital letters but does not recognize words accopmonied by comma or dot (in this example, tag added only to the first "some"):

```
tagger <- function(text, word, tag) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(text, split = " ", fixed = TRUE))
  x[tolower(x) == tolower(word)] <- paste0(tag,
                                            x[tolower(x) == tolower(word)],
                                            tag)
  paste(x, collapse = " ")
  
}

tagger(text = x, word = "some", tag = "<>")
```

```
[1] "<>Some<> random text with some, issues"
```

### Desired result

How can I get a string that will look like 1 or 2?

```
[1] "<>Some<> random text with <>some<>, issues"

[2] "<>Some<> random text with <>some,<> issues"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```r
tagger <- function(text, word, tag) {
  gsub(pattern = paste0("(", word, ")(\\.|,)?"), replacement = paste0(tag, "\\1\\2", tag), x = text, ignore.case = TRUE)
}

x <- "Some random text with some, issues"

tagger(x, "some", "<>")
#> [1] "<>Some<> random text with <>some,<> issues"
```

Comment: you can avoid the comma being inside the tag by this: `gsub(pattern = paste0("(", word, ")(\\,|\\.)?"), 
     replacement = paste0(tag, "\\1", tag, "\\2"), 
     x = x, ignore.case = TRUE)`

Comment: What does `"\\1"` and `"\\2"` in replacement mean?

Comment: These are placeholders. Using parantheses in a a regular expression we make a so-called capturing group. "\\1" refers to the first group, "\\2" to the second, ... In the replacement the placeholders are then replaced with the matched value, i.e. "\\1" is replaced by the `word` = "(word)", "\\2" by an optional "," or "." = "(,|\\.)?"

Comment: @MarBlo Thanks. I have overlooked that. Thought the desired result should include the ","  inside the tags. Best S.